# different appearances of the same color

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

In drawing the following Sangaku with Asymptote, I get different appearances of the same color: `A` and `r` with `purple`. Why is that? and how to fix it?

[image]

```
// Run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
usepackage("xcolor");
unitsize(1cm);
real r=.8, R=1.5;
real d=2sqrt(R*r);
pair A=(0,r), B=(d,R);   // AB^2 = 4Rr
pen pA=purple,pB=red;
draw((-1-r,0)--(d+R+.5,0));
draw(circle(A,r),pA);
draw(circle(B,R),pB);
dot("$A$",(0,0),S,pA,Fill(yellow));  
dot("$B$",(d,0),S,pB,Fill(yellow));
label("$r$",A,pA);
label("$R$",B,pB);
label("${\color{purple}A}{\color{red}B}^2=4{\color{purple}r}{\color{red}R}$",point(NW),SE);
shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```

Comment: well obviously asymptote and xcolor define purple with different values. You will have to adapt one. For asymptote see here https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/doc/Pens.html, for xcolor check the docu.

Comment: In [plain_pens.asy](https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/blob/master/base/plain_pens.asy#L119), `pen purple=rgb(0.5,0,1);`. In [xcolor](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor), `pen purple_=rgb(.75,0,.25);`.

Comment: @NguyenVanChi1998 Can you turn your comment as an answer? it's a bit strange that Asymptote do not use values of `xcolor`, intentionally I guess

Comment: the following works: `usepackage("asycolors");` instead of `usepackage("xcolor");`

Comment: @BlackMild No, I can't. :) Note that [usepackage("asycolors");](https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/blob/master/doc/asycolors.sty#L60) does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using xcolor's definition of purple in asy.

```c
usepackage("xcolor");
unitsize(1cm);
// use xcolor purple
pen purple=rgb(.75,0,.25);
real r=.8, R=1.5;
real d=2sqrt(R*r);
pair A=(0,r), B=(d,R);   // AB^2 = 4Rr
pen pA=purple,pB=red;
draw((-1-r,0)--(d+R+.5,0));
draw(circle(A,r),pA);
draw(circle(B,R),pB);
dot("$A$",(0,0),S,pA,Fill(yellow));  
dot("$B$",(d,0),S,pB,Fill(yellow));
label("$r$",A,pA);
label("$R$",B,pB);
label("${\color{purple}A}{\color{red}B}^2=4{\color{purple}r}{\color{red}R}$",point(NW),SE);
shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));
```